# Zend Framework How can I print a logged in user name from a Zend_Session_Namespace

Tags: zend-framework

Hi all I have created the following login controller for my site and it works fine in relation to logging users in a logging them out. The thing I want to do is echo the logged in users name into the FlashMessenger for the success page how ever as my code stands I only get the following message when redirected to the success page, "you have been successfully logged in as Array".
Can I also ask the following does the line $session->user =$adapter>getResultArray('Password'); create an array of user information less the password value from the database.

Many Thanks in advance,

IrishStudent76

```
 <?php
 class LoginController extends Zend_Controller_Action
 {
  public function init(){    

        $this->view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');

 }

 // login action
public function loginAction()
{
 $form = new PetManager_Form_Login;
 $this->view->form = $form;    

 /* 
   check for valid input from the form and authenticate using adapter
   Add  user record to session and redirect to the original request URL if present
*/
 if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
  if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
    $values = $form->getValues();

    $adapter = new PetManager_Auth_Adapter_Doctrine(
      $values['username'], $values['password']
    );
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
    if ($result->isValid()) {
      $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('petmanager.auth');
      $session->user = $adapter->getResultArray('Password');
      if (isset($session->requestURL)) {
        $url = $session->requestURL;
        unset($session->requestURL);
        $this->_redirect($url);  
      } else {
        $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')
                      ->addMessage('You have been successfully logged in as '.$session-  >user);
        $this->_redirect('/login/success');
      }
    } else {
      $this->view->message = 'You could not be logged in. Please try again.';          
    }        
  }
 }
}

public function successAction() 
{
if ($this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->getMessages()) {
  $this->view->messages = $this->_helper
                               ->getHelper('FlashMessenger')
                               ->getMessages();    
} else {
  $this->_redirect('/login');    
}     
}

public function logoutAction()
{
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->clearIdentity();
Zend_Session::destroy();
$this->_redirect('/');
}

}
```

Comment: Why do you need a separate session to store info about logged user? Cannot you store it in your auth session, .e.g. `$auth->getStorage()->write($whatEverYouWantToStore);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you set the $session->user which you later try to integrate into the Message:

```
$session->user = $adapter->getResultArray('Password');
```

As you can see, you are getting a result array, so no wonder $session->user stores an array. Why don't you use `$auth->getIdentity()` to get the username?

And I'd consider reading [the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.auth.introduction.html), it shows everything in a pretty clear way!

Comment: Depends, maybe it's just called array but is actually a fluid interface.

Comment: It's obviously an array or else the OP wouldn't be getting "Logged in as Array"

Comment: @Phil: Very convincing! :) I should really go to sleep.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Time to go to Bed :-)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to roll your own session auth storage, this is all built in to `Zend_Auth`.

Try something like this...

```
if ($result->isValid()) {
  $identity = $adapter->getResultArray('Password');
  $auth->getStorage()->write($identity);
  $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('petmanager.auth');
  if (isset($session->requestURL)) {
    $url = $session->requestURL;
    unset($session->requestURL);
    $this->_redirect($url);  
  } else {
    $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')
                  ->addMessage('You have been successfully logged in as '.$identity['NameColumn']);
    $this->_redirect('/login/success');
  }
} else {
  $this->view->message = 'You could not be logged in. Please try again.';          
}
```